# Django with django-tenants not copying all static folders to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: django, django-settings

I have a django-tenants site that I am attempting to prepare for moving to a live server. I want to use an AWS S3 bucket for static files. I have been able to get a few folders the local static directory to copy to the S3 bucket but many are not copied when I run "python manage.py collectstatic."

I have the following folders in the static directory: admin, bootstrap, CACHE, constrainedfilefield, core_images, css, django_ckeditor_5, django_extensions, django_tinymce, tagulous, tinymce. However only the following folders are getting copied to the S3 bucket: admin, constrainedfilefield, django_ckeditor_5, django_extensions, django_tinymce, tagulous

settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for config project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.14.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os.path
#from environs import Env
from django.conf.locale.en import formats as en_formats

EMPLOYEE_PERMISSIONS_FILE = 'config.employee_permissions'
MANAGER_PERMISSIONS_FILE = 'config.manager_permissions'
ADMINISTRATOR_PERMISSIONS_FILE = 'config.administrator_permissions'
from importlib import import_module
employee_permissions = import_module(EMPLOYEE_PERMISSIONS_FILE).EMPLOYEE_PERMISSIONS
manager_permissions = import_module(MANAGER_PERMISSIONS_FILE).MANAGER_PERMISSIONS
administrator_permissions = import_module(ADMINISTRATOR_PERMISSIONS_FILE).ADMINISTRATOR_PERMISSIONS


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'securitykeyhere'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

#env = Env()
#env.read_env()


# Application definition

SHARED_APPS = [
    'django_tenants',  # mandatory for django tenants
    'company_accounts',  # tenant model
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    #installed apps
    'tinymce',
    'localflavor',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'crispy_forms',
    'compressor',
    'phone_field',
    'storages',
    # custom apps
    'accounts',
    'pages',
    'public_pages',
    'django_extensions',
]

TENANT_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # installed apps
    #'tinymce',
    'django_ckeditor_5',
    'localflavor',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'crispy_forms',
    'constrainedfilefield',
    'compressor',
    'view_breadcrumbs',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'tagulous',

    # custom apps
    'accounts',
    'pages',
    'search',
    'site_tags',

    #tenant custom apps
    'tenant_customapps.intranet.tenant_howto',
    'tenant_customapps.intranet.company_announcement',
    'tenant_customapps.intranet.company_project',
    'tenant_customapps.intranet.company_document',
    'tenant_customapps.intranet.company_profile',
    'tenant_customapps.intranet.company_badges',
    #'tenant_customapps.intranet.user_profiles',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    # custom middleware for timezones - provided from documents
    'config.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
]



ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

# URLS for the main (non-tenant) site
PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'public_pages.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'context_processors.cname',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
        # ENGINE before switch to django-tenants: 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'passwordhere',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)

TENANT_MODEL = "company_accounts.Tenant" # app.Model

TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL = "company_accounts.Domain"  # app.Model

#setting AUTO_DROP_SCHEMA to True will lead to the deleted tenant's schema being deleted. Default is false
#AUTO_DROP_SCHEMA = True


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'accounts.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

]

SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
    'xml':    'tagulous.serializers.xml_serializer',
    'json':   'tagulous.serializers.json',
    'python': 'tagulous.serializers.python',
    'yaml':   'tagulous.serializers.pyyaml',
}

SITE_ID = 1

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = 'd-m-y'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

#S3 Bucket config
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'keyidhere'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secretkeyhere'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname11'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'


#AWS S3 Settings
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
#DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'mysite.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

#STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static"
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICfILES_DIRs = [
    str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),
]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static"
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
#STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # other finders..
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'




CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

#remove this if using ckeditor
# TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
#     #"height": "320px",
#     #"width": "960px",
#     "menubar": "file edit view insert format tools table help",
#     "plugins": "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview searchreplace visualblocks code "
#     "fullscreen insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount spellchecker",
#     "toolbar": "undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft "
#     "aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist checklist | forecolor "
#     "backcolor casechange permanentpen formatpainter removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | "
#     "fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media pageembed template link anchor codesample | "
#     "a11ycheck ltr rtl | showcomments addcomment code",
#     "custom_undo_redo_levels": 10,
# }

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "django_tenants.files.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage"

#MULTITENANT_RELATIVE_MEDIA_ROOT = ""  # (default: create sub-directory for each tenant)


#Adds permissions to groups that are automatically created when new tenants are added

POST_MIGRATION_GROUP_CREATION = {
    "Employee":employee_permissions,
    "Manager":manager_permissions,
    "Administrator":administrator_permissions,
}

BREADCRUMBS_TEMPLATE = "tenant_customapps/breadcrumbs.html"

BREADCRUMBS_HOME_LABEL = "Home"

customColorPalette = [
    {"color": "hsl(4, 90%, 58%)", "label": "Red"},
    {"color": "hsl(340, 82%, 52%)", "label": "Pink"},
    {"color": "hsl(291, 64%, 42%)", "label": "Purple"},
    {"color": "hsl(262, 52%, 47%)", "label": "Deep Purple"},
    {"color": "hsl(231, 48%, 48%)", "label": "Indigo"},
    {"color": "hsl(207, 90%, 54%)", "label": "Blue"},
]
CKEDITOR_5_CONFIGS = {
    "default": {
        "toolbar": [
            "heading",
            "|",
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "link",
            "bulletedList",
            "numberedList",
            "blockQuote",
            "imageUpload"
        ],
    },
    "comment": {
        "language": {"ui": "en", "content": "en"},
        "toolbar": [
            "heading",
            "|",
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "link",
            "bulletedList",
            "numberedList",
            "blockQuote",
        ],
    },
    "extends": {
        "language": "en",
        "blockToolbar": [
            "paragraph",
            "heading1",
            "heading2",
            "heading3",
            "|",
            "bulletedList",
            "numberedList",
            "|",
            "blockQuote",
        ],
        "toolbar": [
            "heading",
            "codeBlock",
            "|",
            "outdent",
            "indent",
            "|",
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "link",
            "underline",
            "strikethrough",
            "code",
            "subscript",
            "superscript",
            "highlight",
            "|",
            "bulletedList",
            "numberedList",
            "todoList",
            "|",
            "blockQuote",
            "insertImage",
            "|",
            "fontSize",
            "fontFamily",
            "fontColor",
            "fontBackgroundColor",
            "mediaEmbed",
            "removeFormat",
            "insertTable",
            "sourceEditing",
        ],
        "image": {
            "toolbar": [
                "imageTextAlternative",
                "|",
                "imageStyle:alignLeft",
                "imageStyle:alignRight",
                "imageStyle:alignCenter",
                "imageStyle:side",
                "|",
                "toggleImageCaption",
                "|"
            ],
            "styles": [
                "full",
                "side",
                "alignLeft",
                "alignRight",
                "alignCenter",
            ],
        },
        "table": {
            "contentToolbar": [
                "tableColumn",
                "tableRow",
                "mergeTableCells",
                "tableProperties",
                "tableCellProperties",
            ],
            "tableProperties": {
                "borderColors": customColorPalette,
                "backgroundColors": customColorPalette,
            },
            "tableCellProperties": {
                "borderColors": customColorPalette,
                "backgroundColors": customColorPalette,
            },
        },
        "heading": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "model": "paragraph",
                    "title": "Paragraph",
                    "class": "ck-heading_paragraph",
                },
                {
                    "model": "heading1",
                    "view": "h1",
                    "title": "Heading 1",
                    "class": "ck-heading_heading1",
                },
                {
                    "model": "heading2",
                    "view": "h2",
                    "title": "Heading 2",
                    "class": "ck-heading_heading2",
                },
                {
                    "model": "heading3",
                    "view": "h3",
                    "title": "Heading 3",
                    "class": "ck-heading_heading3",
                },
            ]
        },
        "list": {
            "properties": {
                "styles": True,
                "startIndex": True,
                "reversed": True,
            }
        },
        "htmlSupport": {
            "allow": [
                {"name": "/.*/", "attributes": True, "classes": True, "styles": True}
            ]
        },
    },
}

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'static/'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```